# A minimal `Paragraph ended before \@@hyperref was complete`

Tags: hyperref

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref} % hyper-referencing/link capabilities in PDF

\begin{document}

    \hyperref{http://vulkan-spec-chunked.ahcox.com/ch31s03.html#VkFormat}{test}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this minimal example will give the error:

```
line 11: Paragraph ended before \@@hyperref was complete.
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use command `\href` instead of `\hyperref` like

```
\documentclass{minimal}%minimal standalone

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref} % hyper-referencing/link capabilities in PDF

\begin{document}

% \hyperref{http://vulkan-spec-chunked.ahcox.com/ch31s03.html#VkFormat}{test}
\href{http://vulkan-spec-chunked.ahcox.com/ch31s03.html#VkFormat}{test} % <===========

\end{document}
```

Which gives the text `text` and the link if you move the mouse on it:

[image]